# What can be the event similar to onpopstate that works across documents?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-history, popstate

From mozilla docs:

> A **popstate** event is dispatched to the window every time the active
>   history entry changes between two history entries for the **SAME**
>   **DOCUMENT**.

Which window event should i use if i need to listen to 'session history changes' **ACROSS DOCUMENTS** in a browsing context?

I am writing a js library that helps tracking navigation when user use back/forward browser buttons. The library would record when user is navigated from page B to page A (backwards) or page A to page B(forward). I've achieved the tracking for the pages that use hashes using the 'popstate' event but when user navigate from page A to page B this event doesn't work.

I've looked at pageshow/pagehide events but they fires on simple page loads as well and not just when the 'session history' changes (ie page fetched from history).

What should i be looking at to know "browser has looked into session history to fetch the current page"?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to handle the Window's `beforeunload` event, and also put code on whichever page loading event is appropriate for your use case.

Note that for `beforeunload`, you don't have time to write something server-side.  You'll have to track this in LocalStorage.

Comment: but 'beforeunload' won't have any information about the page being navigated TO right? if i visited pages A,B,C,D on a site and press back button on 'D', beforeunload would just tell me user is going to leave page D and nothing like "C is going to be fetched from history".
In case of popstate, it fires in between 2 state of documents, i was looking for similar that fires 'after D is navigated and just before C is going to load' so I know user has used something to go back in history (or forward in history)

Comment: No, of course not.  It's up to your code on the page you land on to check whatever breadcrumb might have been left over in LocalStorage from the previous page.  Your page doesn't get to know where the browser is going.

Comment: Thanks, can you please look into the more detailed edit of my question, it should be much more clear now. Still don't think i can use beforeunload as i want something concrete that related to 'history' object.

Comment: I'm telling you that what you want specifically doesn't exist, but you can emulate the behavior with what I'm suggesting to you.

Comment: not sure who did that, i didn't. let me upvote both answers so that can be reversed somehow.

Comment: Note that even if I don't see how it would help, you can [write to server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) from beforeunload event.

Answer (score 0):

There is something weird in your requirements:

You say you are writing a js library, but for this library to work across different documents, for a start, it would at least have to be executed on every documents navigated by the user.

And even if it were the case, there wouldn't be any solid way to do what you want.

Browsers' behavior regarding history navigation vary a lot:

For instance, FF will keep in memory its current state, and will not reload the page per se, but simply reactivate its saved state (i.e you won't even be able to know that the user came back to this page <sub>(apart from ugly polling of [`performance.navigation.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type), which despite what MDN says is only absent in Safari).</sub>

---

So all in all, what you want to make is a job for a [browser extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history), not for a web-library.

Comment: Thank you, but I think the Performance interface isn't available outside FF (may be IE). Was looking for something thats using window's events that are supported across browsers.

I have edited the entire question, please have a look.

Comment: @p_champ MDN's table is wrong, Chrome does support performance.timing.type, only Safari doesn't. But since your edit changed completely the question, I also changed completely my answer, and you may not like it...

Comment: ok lets say its a browser extension and not a library and separate for chrome/safari/ff, what do you suggest i should use?

Comment: I am not really in the `chrome://` side of the force, but I thought the link I provided to the *chrome://History API* would be a good start, since it can access the whole browser history, and has events too.